# How does Chrome display esoteric unicode characters

Tags: google-chrome, unicode, fonts, emoji, conemu

Here are two cool and esoteric Unicode characters: ⌀ and ⎘. I'm trying to debug why these two characters aren't showing correctly in my ConEmu shell, which instead shows ugly rectangles with a question mark.

What is confusing to me is that when I paste these characters in Chrome, they show perfectly. I initially considered that maybe Chrome is using a better font than ConEmu which has more characters, but even when I set Chrome to use the same Consolas font as ConEmu, it shows the symbols correctly. In my anger, I even had Chrome render a sentence containing these symbols using the "Comic Sans MS" font, only to see that Chrome cheerfully continues to succeed in rendering these symbols.

**What is Chrome's trick for rendering symbols correctly when the fonts don't define glyphs for them?** Does it have some kind of fallback font that it uses? I'm hoping that whatever trick this is, I could use it in ConEmu as well.

Comment: Likely this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/input/font-technology

Comment: It seems that Chrome's approach varies according to the OS; see [RenderText and Chrome UI text drawing](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/rendertext/). On Windows (only) it uses font linking, as described in the link in the comment from @MarkTolonen above. Also see the video [RenderingNG: The next-generation rendering architecture for Chrome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUbJPHYKZkU), especially the _Pipeline_ section @ 4:51, for an overview of how rendering works in Chrome.

Comment: If the font that's set through CSS doesn't have the glyph it falls back to the OS ones, which will at least have a "bogus" font (the one with the rectangles you talked about). The odd one isn't Chrome here, it's your *ConEmu shell*, why isn't it falling back to the OS fonts is weird.